# I can't use idaapi.cmd in IDA 7.5

Tags: plugins, ida

As title say, i try to make a plugin named rizzo used in IDA 7.5 by using python3. But when i try to run this plugin, the IDA will error like this:
 `for n in range(0, len(idaapi.cmd.Operands)):`
`AttributeError: module 'idaapi' has no attribute 'cmd'`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyp2u.png)

i want to know how to solve this error, thanks

Comment: `cmd` doesn't exist in 7.5, use `insn_t()`.

Answer (score 0):

replace `idaapi.cmd.Operands` with `idaapi.insn_t().ops`